# when to reference a property that is not a valid identifier, how can I use segment-literal notation?

Tags: handlebars.js

In the document [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html)

```
{{#each articles.[10].[#comments]}}
   <h1>{{subject}}</h1>
   <div>
    {{body}}
   </div>
{{/each}}
```

but I want such use it

```
{{#each nav-list.value}}
    <li class="nav-{{@index}}">
        {{{../[content.value].value}}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Obviously， it dons't work! How should I implement this...

Comment: I konw how to do it. [issue](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1304)

Comment: can you share the answer please?

Comment: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1304